# $f:D\subset \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R$, where $D$ is a compact and convex set, reaches it maximum at $int(D)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm trying to prove that if $D$ is a compact and convex (for every two elements of $D$, the line that connects them is contained in $D$) then:

> If $f:D\subset \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R$ and at every point of $Boundary(D)$ the gradient of $f$ is in the direction of $Int (D)$ then  $f$ reaches it maximum in an element of it's domain interior; Int (D).

I'm completely lost with this one, most of all with the gradient hypothesis. Do you know how to prove this?

Ok, so as Hans Engler suggested in the comments below I did this:

> Suppose that $f$ reaches a maximum at a point in $Boundary (D)$, $(x_0,y_0)$. Since the gradient points towards $Int (D)$ and since $D$ is convex then we know that there is another point $(x_i,y_i)$ in D that lies in the line $(x_i,y_i)=(x_0,y_0)+t( \partial f / \partial x,\partial f / \partial y)$. But how do I know that as matter of fact f reaches a maximum in this line?

Comment: If you start at any point and walk a bit in the direction of the gradient, the function value increases.

Comment: Great, but how could I write that fact?

Comment: Use it for a contradiction argument.

Comment: Ok so I wrote the following: Suppose that $f$ reaches a maximum at a point in $Boundary (f)$, $(x_0,y_0)$. Since the gradient points towards $Int (D)$ and since $D$ is convex then we know that there is another point $(x_i,y_i)$ in D that lies in the line $(x_i,y_i)=(x_0,y_0)+t( \partial f / \partial x,\partial f / \partial y)$. But how do I know that as matter of fact f reaches a maximum in this line?

Comment: You don't have to. All you know is that it increased along the line, so there's some point other than your boundary point where $f$ is larger, thus the boundary point isn't where a max happens

Comment: Note that you know a max happens *somewhere* in D by compactness. The thing to prove is that it cant be at any boundary point.